# PATINDEX to detect letters and six numbers

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012.

table a

```
Id   name               number
1    py/ut/455656/ip     null
2    py/ut/jl/op         null
3    py/utr//grt         null
```

I want to retrieve the numbers

```
 Id   name               number
1    py/ut/455656/ip     455656
2    py/ut/jl/op         null
3    py/utr//grt         null
```

here the sql script

```
update table a 
set number=SUBSTRING(name,PATINDEX('py/u/[0-9]',name)+6,6)
```

I need to retrieve the number after `py/ut` and before the `/` . The script works well if there is a number. For the second row it is delivering `jl/op`

The number always get six algarisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `where` clause:

```
update table a 
    set number = SUBSTRING(name, PATINDEX('py/u/[0-9]', name) + 6, 6)
    where name like '%py/u/[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score 2):

check this :

```
declare @Number nvarchar(20)='py/ut/455656/ip'



Declare @intAlpha int
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @Number )
BEGIN
WHILE @intAlpha > 0
BEGIN
SET @Number  = STUFF(@Number , @intAlpha, 1, '' )
SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @Number  )
END
END
select @Number
```

Comment: This answer is great. Can you kindly explain the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If name field contain only one number this script should work for you : 
What did I do:

- I have used `PATINDEX()` to find which point the number starts.
- Also, again I used `PATINDEX()` with `REVERSE()` name to find end point.
- I used `LEN()` to find total length the field.
- Then finally I used `SUBSTRING()` to capture number from starting point to total length - (starting point) - (end point).

Check it:

```
--DROP TABLE #A
--GO
CREATE TABLE #A
(
    id  int
    ,name   VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #A
    VALUES (1, 'py/ut/455656/ip')
    , (2, 'py/ut/jl/op    ')
    , (3, 'py/utr//grt    ')

SELECT
    id
    ,name
    /*
   ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', name) - 1 --starting poing
   ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(name)) - 1 --reverse starting point
   */
   ,CASE WHEN (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', name) - 1)>0 
    THEN SUBSTRING(name
                  ,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', name), 
                   LEN(NAME) - (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', name) - 1) - (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(name)) - 1)
                  )
    ELSE null END Number
FROM #A
```

Answer (score 1):

PATINDEX works like the LIKE operator, so the pattern you're using is actually returning 0 for both rows and is just coincidentally working for the value that has 6 numbers starting after the py/ut/ part.  You need to add a wildcard to the pattern you're passing into PATINDEX and a WHERE clause to the UPDATE statement.

Try something like this:

```
-- Length of the path prefix, assumes it is constant
DECLARE @lenPrefix int
set @lenPrefix = 6

DECLARE @lenNumber int
SET @lenNumber = 6

UPDATE TABLE a 
SET number=SUBSTRING(name, PATINDEX('py/ut/[0-9]%', name) + @lenPrefix, @lenNumber)
WHERE 
  PATINDEX('py/ut/[0-9]%', name) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @a TABLE([name] NVARCHAR(MAX), number INT NULL)
INSERT @a([name]) VALUES ('py/ut/455656/ip'), ('py/ut/jl/op'), ('py/utr//grt')

UPDATE @a 
SET number = SUBSTRING([name], PATINDEX('%/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/%', [name]) + 1, 6)
WHERE [name] LIKE '%/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/%'

SELECT * FROM @a
```

Make the pattern more or less specific to taste.